# Row Autosize containing carriage-returned data

Tags: vba, excel

I've been working on doing a simple import VBA command to bring in data from another excel sheet, containing data from a reporting tool we use. The data has been outputted in such a way that one cell contains multiline text, as if someone had written it using alt+enter to get a carriage return.

I've tried to autosize these rows to have the data properly show, but when I do this is autosizes to one row of text only. Is there a way I can get autosize to work with multiline text, preferably through VBA?

I have tried this code before to use autosize, but it hasn't worked due to the issue I stated before where autosize just makes it one line

```
For counter = 1 To entries

    Rows(counter).EntireRow.AutoFit

Next
```

EDIT: I should mention the cell in question that needs to be autofit is a merged cell, and it is text wrapped. Apologies for not including it prior.

Comment: try setting wraptext before autofitting

Comment: wrap text is already enabled, it doesn't do anything

Comment: do you have any merged cells? I always had this problem with autofiting merged cells.

Comment: Yes the cell in question is a merged cell

Answer (score 0):

If my cells contain long text, using Rows(counter).EntireRow.AutoFit would not able to show all the text. I need to set the width of the columns to their max before using your code:

```
    Columns("A:AA").ColumnWidth = 200  'depends on possible max width and which columns
    Columns("A:AA").EntireColumn.AutoFit

    For counter = 1 To entries
        Rows(counter).EntireRow.AutoFit
    Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is in cells format (wrap)

Try this way

```
For counter = 1 To entries
    Rows(counter).WrapText = True
    Rows(counter).EntireRow.AutoFit
Next
```

EDIT:

If you have merged cells on different rows you can try something like this:

```
'I set number of rows and columns only for example
entries = 10
LastCol = 20

Set Rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(entries, LastCol))
For Each mCell In Rng
    If Not mCell.Value = "" Then
        If mCell.Address <> mCell.MergeArea.Address Then
            mStr = CStr(mCell.Value)
            mLF = 1
            For x = 1 To Len(mStr)
                If Mid(mStr, x, 1) = vbCr Or Mid(mStr, x, 1) = vbLf Then
                    mLF = mLF + 1
                End If
            Next x
            mHeight = mLF * 7 'Set the value you need for each line of text
            Range(mCell.MergeArea.Address).RowHeight = mHeight
        End If
    End If
Next mCell
```

Comment: Text wrap is already enabled on the cell. Sorry for not mentioning it before. This is what I had been trying (effectively) to no result)

Comment: It's strange It worked for me! Are you sure that after pasting to cells wraptext is still enabled?

Comment: Yes, When I've been creating the merged cells as I need them via VBA, it's been Merging, setting center alignment, and then enabling text wrap. Sadly its not working out the way I had planned. I've tried fiddling with the settings just from the ribbon and haven't had any luck either.

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question to include more info. How many cells were merged? Any other text in other columns of the same row? If you can post your sample input and the desired output, it would be easier to solve the question. Thanks.